# SQL First Product and Second Product Combinations

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to find what the preferred combination of item purchases for customers who have shopped here. Currently, this code tells me the number of combinations, but this a) does not tell me which product was purchased first and second and b) tells me all the possible combinations of customers' varying frequency.

The data I currently have looks something like this:

```
CustomerKey    CalendarDate     PnLCategory     ChannelName          
    8          2014-06-27         Laptop            Online
    8          2015-07-01         Mouse             Retail 
    8          2015-12-13         Earphones         Online 
    10         2014-01-10         Headphones        Retail
    14         2016-01-25         Laptop            Online
    14         2017-02-18         Mouse             Retail
```

Based on this data, you can find that customers typically purchase a laptop then mouse. Additionally, you can tell that customers typically purchase online than retail.

I only care about the first two transactions a customer makes. Also, how would you include which channel the product was purchased from? Ideally, would like to be able to know what second product a customer would likely purchase given first product and in which channel.

```
    SELECT A.PnLCategory, B.PnLCategory, COUNT (*) CountForCombination 
    FROM MyTable3 A
    INNER JOIN MyTable3 B
    ON A.CustomerKey = B.CustomerKey
    AND A.PnLCategory < B.PnLCategory  
    GROUP BY A.PnLCategory, B.PnLCategory 
    ORDER BY CountForCombination desc
```

Successful result would look something like:

```
FirstProduct     ChannelName1     SecondProduct     ChannelName2     #Occurences
  Laptop             Online           Mouse              Retail          100
  Mouse              Retail           Headphones         Online          50
```

Comment: Do you have any timestamp in that table ?

Comment: Yeah, I have calendar dates for each transaction made

Comment: Edit your question and provide samle data and desired results.

Comment: Can you add more information Like Table Structure and Sample data.

Comment: Added desired table structure result

Comment: You have to provide more information on your table (structure and data) so we can evaluate and create the sql statement on your problem.

Comment: Updated again - first time I've posted a question so wasn't sure how much to provide